# Where is org.gridgain.grid.GridRichNode in GridGain 6.0.3

Tags: gridgain

i couldn't find GridRichNode in GridGain 6.0.3, is there an alternative to this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridRichNode was removed in GridGain 6.0.3 to remove duplicity that existed between GridNode and GridRichNode APIs.

To get the same functionality as for GridRichNode, you now need to get a projection over a specific node, like so:

```
GridNode node = ...; // Get a single node.

GridProjection nodePrj = grid.forNode(node);

// Send a message to specific node.
nodePrj.send(...)
```